# added a new record using ajax and codeigniter.i want to redirect to the view page after adding record. so i want to get the last insert id

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Ajax function and controller action is given below.anyone can help to get the last insertid to redirect.the redirection is done in ajax success function. can it do in controller action.its not getting

Ajax function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#rfqsubmit').click(function () {

        //var title = $('#title').val();

        var form_data = {
            title: $('#txtname').val(),
            merid: $('#mermerchant').val(),
            userid: $('#customer').val(),
            description: $('#txtrequirement').val(),
            reqid: $('#requirementid').val(),
            shipmethod: $('#shipmethod').val(),
            shiplocation: $('#shiplocation').val(),
            attachment: $('#txtattachments').val(),
            bidclose: $('#txtbidclose').val(),
            ajax: '1'
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/RFQ/addoffline",
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            success: function () {

                 window.location.href ="<?php  echo base_url() ?>moderator/Employee/manageemployee/";
                // window.location.href ="<?php //echo base_url()             ?>moderator/RFQ/viewrfq/"+  form_data.reqid;
//      alert('added Successfully');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

</script>
```

Controller action

```
     $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
           $this->load->helper('file');
        $data7 = array(
            'rfq_title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'rfq_detail' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'rfq_merchantid' => $this->input->post('merid'),
            'rfq_userid' => $this->input->post('userid'),

        );
       $add= $this->requirement_model->forminsert($data7);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear anyhow if i got what you need try this.

> in your controller action return json response:

```
   $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
             $this->load->helper('file');
             $data7 = array(
                'rfq_title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'rfq_detail' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'rfq_merchantid' => $this->input->post('merid'),
                'rfq_userid' => $this->input->post('userid'),

            );
           $inserted_id= $this->requirement_model->forminsert($data7);
           //your forminsert method in model should return 
           //$this->db->insert_id();
           $response=array('id'=>$inserted_id,'message'=>"inserted successfully"); 
           echo json_encode($response); 
           die();
    }
```

> Your model function return last_inserted_id:

```
public function forminsert($data7) 
{ 
$this->db->insert('jil_mrorfq',$data7); 
//it will return last id
return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

> Now in ajax success :

```
   $.ajax({
         url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/RFQ/addoffline",
         type: 'POST',
         data: form_data,
         dataType:"Json",
         success: function (data) {
         //to access that id
         var last_inserted_id = data.id;
         window.location.href ="<?php  echo base_url() ?>moderator/Employee/manageemployee/"+last_inserted_id;

         }
        });
```

Comment: i wil clear my question. i added record. and i want to redirect to view page.for that  i need last insert id. how it get?

Comment: this is your redirect:
 window.location.href ="<?php  echo base_url() ?>moderator/Employee/manageemployee/";

what problem with it ?

Comment: i want to pass last insert id as parameter with redirect.

Comment: var last_inserted_id = data.id;
                window.location.href ="<?php  echo base_url() ?>moderator/Employee/manageemployee/"+last_inserted_id; i did so. but id is not getting

Comment: show me your `$this->requirement_model->forminsert($data7)` function

Comment: public function forminsert($data7)
{
     $this->db->insert('jil_mrorfq',$data7);
}

Comment: http://localhost/jiklink/moderator/Employee/manageemployee/undefined this is getting after ajax call. id is not getting,coming as undefined

Comment: let me edit my question again ,
you don;t read answer well,
copy ajax function exactly what i wrote 
it has modification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97365/discussion-between-angel-and-abdul-manan).